# Как добавить символы перевода строки в json на python3

Tags: python, json

Получаю по API структуру данных в json, разбираю ее при помощи json.loads(), меняю некоторые значения, далее пытаюсь собрать назад строку json в том же формате и передать ее в параметрах POST запроса.
Как из словаря получить строку с символами \n? Вот для примера оставил небольшой кусок от реальной структуры данных

```
  import json
    
    class card(object):
        def __init__(self):
            self.cardapi = """
                {
                  "beginDate": "2021-04-14T00:00:00",
                  "insuranceMonth": 12,
                  "prevPolicySerial": "ХХХ",
                  "prevPolicyNumber": "0123456789"
                }
                """
    
            self.card = json.loads(self.cardapi)
    
    
    a = card()
    
    a.card["beginDate"] = "2022-04-14T00:00:00"
    
    data = a.cardapi.encode('UTF-8')
    print(data)
    """
    json выводится вот в таком формате, в таком виде сервер его принимает
    b'\n {\n "beginDate": "2021-04-14T00:00:00",\n "insuranceMonth": 12,\n "prevPolicySerial": "\xd0\xa5\xd0\xa5\xd0\xa5",\n "prevPolicyNumber": "0123456789"\n }\n '
    """
response = requests.post(endpoint, headers=headers, data=data)
if response.status_code == 200:
    print(response.json(), flush=True)
"""
{'success': True, 'error': None, 'data': {'id': 1080110}}
"""

    data = str(a.card).replace("'", '"').encode('UTF-8')
    print(data)
    """
    json выводится вот в таком формате, без символов \n сервер его не принимает
    b'{"beginDate": "2022-04-14T00:00:00", "insuranceMonth": 12, "prevPolicySerial": "\xd0\xa5\xd0\xa5\xd0\xa5", "prevPolicyNumber": "0123456789"}'

{'success': False, 'error': 'Запрос пришел пустым', 'data': None}
    """
    data = json.dumps(a.card, indent=4)
    print(data)
    """
    json выводится вот в таком формате, сервер его не принимает
    {
        "beginDate": "2022-04-14T00:00:00",
        "insuranceMonth": 12,
        "prevPolicySerial": "\u0425\u0425\u0425",
        "prevPolicyNumber": "0123456789"
    }
    """
```

Comment: Как именно не принимает, что сервер отвечает-то? Как вы определили, что проблема именно в `\n` а не в чём-то другом?

Comment: изменил немного код, я дальше подставляю полученный json в POST запрос, на все варианты кроме первого сервер отвечает {'success': False, 'error': 'Запрос пришел пустым', 'data': None}